# Should a user ID be a secret

Tags: security

I've read some things about hashing the user's ID (DB Primary Key) and keeping it a secret, but I can't really see why.

I'm creating a REST API with which you can retrieve resources from a certain user. Depending on the logged in user, he/she will receive public resources and, if authorized, private resources.

Is it bad to do something like this:

`.../resources?user_id=17`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the user will have to be identified by *some* id. Even if the public ID you're exposing is a hashed version of the actual id or some other random number... then *that* will be its public id. It doesn't really help you much at all.

There's only one argument for randomising the id: if you do not want people to simply scrape your content by incrementing a counter. Randomising the id makes it just a little bit harder to do so. Other than that: ask yourself what somebody can do *knowing the id*. Hopefully nothing, because your application is secure otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

If you set the right permissions and disallow other users from abusing that ID, then it doesn't matter whether the ID is public or private.

You could of course use a separate ID to publicly represent the user, and use the private ID for permissions.